# cannot create new variable with mutate after using gather function tidyverse.

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

Hi every one this is the trouble Im facing.

I have a dataframe that it is in a wrong format.

as this. 

 `id | 1/3/2017| 1/4/2017 |
 a  | 4       | 4        |
 b  | 5       | 5        |
 c  | 6       | 6        |
 d  | 7       | 7        |`

Obviously I want the tidy format like this and, an additional column with a 00:00:00 hour

 `id |   date   |   hour  |data|
 a  | 1/3/2017 |00:00:00 |4   |
 b  | 1/3/2017 |00:00:00 |5   |
 c  | 1/3/2017 |00:00:00 |6   |
 d  | 1/3/2017 |00:00:00 |7   |
 a  | 1/4/2017 |00:00:00 |4   |
 b  | 1/4/2017 |00:00:00 |5   |
 c  | 1/4/2017 |00:00:00 |6   |
 d  | 1/3/2017 |00:00:00 |7   |`

The code for doing this is the following

`data <- data %>%
gather(date, data, "1/3/2017":"1/4/2017")`

`data <- data %>%
mutate(hour = rep("00:00:00", ncol(data)))`

This makes my code very longer than I would want but, the function I liked to use does not work

`data <- data %>%
gather(date, data, "1/3/2017":"1/4/2017") %>%
mutate(hour = rep("00:00:00", ncol(data)`

The error message that I get is the following

`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column`hora`must be length 30140 (the number of rows) or one, not 220`

I would appreaciate your help because I'm new in R and don't know why this is happening, my intuition is that something is wrong when I specify the enviroment where is performed the operation wit the `%>%` magrittr pipe operator, but don't know how to specify the correct enviroment.

I'm sorry for my bad writing but my native language is spanish and I'm a little slow with foreign languages.

Cheers. And thank you all.

Comment: `data <- data %>% gather(date, data, 2:3) %>% mutate(hour = "00:00:00")`

Comment: Well thank you, that was very efficient. Have a nice day.

Comment: @donlelek, post as answer (and explain)?

Comment: Sorry, didn't have time yesterday, I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your objective, you can use:

```
data <- data %>% 
  gather(date, data, 2:3) %>% 
  mutate(hour = "00:00:00")
```

In your example, your second attempt fails in the `mutate()` line. The problem is the `ncol(data)` argument in the `rep()` call is not yielding the right length. When you mutate a variable, your function should yield either length 1 or the length of the data, in this case:

```
length("00:00:00")
[1] 1
```

So you don't actually need to repeat it. But in some cases, you do have to provide a vector with the same length as the data. In your example you are trying to do it by providing `ncol(data)`, the problem is that it is not clear what `data` you want to call.

In your example:

```
ncol(data)
[1] 3
```

Well, that's neither length 1 nor the length of your data (after `gather`). One solution would be to provide the number of rows of the data by changing to `nrow`,  but be careful, if you do `nrow(data)` you will get the length of the original data, and not the data from the previous step. To use the data you get after the `gather` step use `nrow(.)`, here the dot is a placeholder for the result of the previous step.

So this should work too:

```
data %>% 
  gather(date, data, 2:3) %>%
  mutate(hour = rep("00:00:00", nrow(.)))
```

I hope this clarifies the problem with your original code and solves your problem.

Buena suerte!

Comment: I forgot to mention that is very confusing when you use the same name in multiple variables and objects, in your case the data is called data, and there is a variable called data too.